# JavaScript doesn't work with Apex command Button

Tags: apex, javascript, class, visualforce

I was able to get the id of the button but no able to get the outputText id. Please help

```
  <script >

  function exButton(){

   var remainingValues = document.getElementById("j_id0:j_id5:remaining").value;

    if(remainingValues > 0){
    document.getElementById("j_id0:j_id5:btn").click();
     }

    }
    function period(){

    setInterval("exButton()",50000)

    }

    </script>
```

Apex button//

```
  <apex:commandButton id="btn" action="{!CreatePlan}" reRender="CreatePlan, Debug" value="Request Values" status="CreatePlanStatus"  onClick="period();" />
```

Here is the outputfield

```
    <apex:outputPanel id="Debug" layout="block">
       <h2>Remaining Values</h2><br/>
      <apex:outputText id="remaining" value="{!Debug}"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Can you describe what this code's behavior is supposed to be and why you're using this pattern? It looks like you first click the button, start a timer which runs the exButton function every 50 seconds, at the time of the button click a partial page postback occurs and it rerenders the panel which contains the `outputText` data. Every 50 seconds the exButton function runs again and if the value of the `outputText` is greater than zero, you start yet another timer by clicking the button again and causing another partial postback and a rerender. Is this correct?

Comment: You might consider using the [`<apex:actionPoller >`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionPoller.htm) tag if you can. It'll probably simplify the behavior of the page and you won't have to worry about the element ID values in the page before (or after) the rerender takes place.

Comment: Mark, that is exactly what the script is doing. Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visualforce takes over element Ids and often alters them. Have you checked the actual Id that is being rendered by Visualforce on your button? You may need to get creative with your Javascript to select your button.

EDIT: One common way to deal with this Id issue is to use the jQuery EndsWith() selector:

```
j$('[id$="btn"]');
```

Comment: Hi Greenstork, how can I see the actual id that is bein rendered. any ideas?

Comment: Right click on the button and inspect the element using Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: This is the ID I am  getting id="j_id0:j_id5:btn", is that right?

Comment: That's exactly what I was talking about. Visualforce takes over your Id. You can use jQuery to select the id using the EndsWith() selector. j$('[id$="btn"]');

Comment: Thank you so much! I used the Id above and it works. Appreciate it!

Comment: @Carlos, do you mean that your javascript now has that element Id value hardcoded into it?: `if (value > 0) { document.getElementById("j_id0:j_id5:btn").click(); }`

Comment: Hi mark, yes that's the id of the apex command button

Comment: but for some reason it works fine with the button id but no for a apex:outputfield

Comment: Greenstork, I just updaded my question, would you please help me here. I was able to get the button id but I can't get the outputText id. I will appreciate it!

Comment: Visualforce alters all Ids, do the same thing, look at the Id on the rendered page. The reason to use jQuery is because Visualforce always ends with the id label you specified, even when it prepends all of its jibber jabber. You've ignored my advice to use jQuery but I think you should reconsider. The reason I suggest so is because you can't control the jibber jabber prepended, it could vary and Salesforce could change it. They should always leave the id you specified though as what the rendered id ends with.

Comment: I didn't ignore it, i don't know Jquery :), could you please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can put  alert("xxx") into the function of
period and exButton.then You can find out where problem is.